# Simulate Physical Network Connection in VirtualBox

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization, network-adapter

Is there any way to set simulate a physical daisy-chain link of ethernet cables in VirtualBox? For example:

Node A is on subnet 1 (lets say 192.168.11.101) with 1 NIC

Node B is on subnet 2 (192.168.21.101) with 2 NICs bridged together

Node C is also on subnet 2 (192.168.21.102) with 2 NICs as above

And node D is on subnet 1 (192.168.11.102) with 1 NIC

I want a way to simulate a cable connecting A to B, a cable connecting B to C, and a cable connecting C to D; when I ping D from A, I want it to travel through B and C. I can get this working on physical machines with cables, but I'd like to it with vms.

Thanks for any help you guys can provide :)

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed. We will go from node A to D in configuration. I'm assuming each node is a VM.

For sake of ease, we shall use the 192.168 range and make /24 networks (the third octet changes for network eg 192.168.0 and 192.168.1) For each of these a virtual Nic will be required for each address.

```
Node A NIC 1 Address: 192.168.0.1

Node B NIC 1 Address 192.168.0.2
       NIC 2 Address 192.168.1.1

Node C NIC 1 address 192.168.1.2
       NIC 2 address 192.168.2.1

Node D NIC 1 address 192.168.2.2
```

These will want to be internet networking NICs. A bridged NIC will connect to a physical NIC and exchanges network packets directly. In other words its on your real network. For this test we just want to be internal.

You will also need to set up static routing, the exact way that is done depends on your operating system.

For example Node B you will want it to say "If a packet comes in for the 192.168.0.0 range, send it to 192.168.0.1. If a packet comes in for 192.168.1.0 or 192.168.2.0 send it to 192.168.1.2."